# What Windows error code for expired license?

Tags: windows, error-code

My C# Windows program checks the license and exits if the license is expired after showing an explanation popup.

What exit code should I use when exiting in such a case?

```
Environment.Exit(exitCode);
```

Searching [the 0-15999 Windows error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms681381.aspx) did not lead me to any obvious one.

Comment: Why that's so burning? You can use any exit code >0 unless you are using that exit code some where else.

Comment: @Rahul Error codes are for something, they can help some users and scripts determine what is going wrong. I believe that using the standard error code for this type of errors is better than using an undocumented one.

Comment: Yes that's correct but I meant to say application exit code. You can return the proper error code but internally can use any valid exit code (probably the error code itself)

Comment: Standard error codes are not better, there is no innocent "license expired" error code defined in Windows.  it may lead the user onto a wild goose chase thinking that all the Google hits he gets are accurate.  This can get out of hand pretty badly sometimes, he'll reinstall the operating system.  You have half a billion error codes available to use for your own error reporting, look in WinError.h for the pattern.  If you already report the error then an exit code of 1 is sufficient to indicate gross failure.

Answer (score 1):

Using exit code `1` is OK.

From Hans Passant's comment:

> Standard error codes are not better, there is no innocent "license expired" error code defined in Windows. it may lead the user onto a wild goose chase thinking that all the Google hits he gets are accurate. This can get out of hand pretty badly sometimes, he'll reinstall the operating system. You have half a billion error codes available to use for your own error reporting, look in WinError.h for the pattern. If you already report the error then an exit code of 1 is sufficient to indicate gross failure.